# Modifying a method so the arguments can be any type that implements Comparable

Tags: java, generics

I would like to modify the following method so its arguments can be of any type that implements the `Comparable` interface. The method’s return type should be the same as the type of its parameter variables.

```
public static int max(int a, int b) {   
    if (a >b) 
        return a;  
    else 
        return b;
}
```

So in modifying it, I could just use `<T extends Comparable<T>>`, but how would I go about making the return types the same?

Comment: You're very close to the answer. You should show more of what you've done rather than just saying it. It will likely encourage someone to post the answer, or it will click.

Comment: Haha yah ive been trying to get these generics for the past 4 days im just about over the whole java generics thing haha

Comment: for best results use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You essentially want something like this:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(T a, T b) {
    int n = a.compareTo(b);
    if (n > 0)
        return a;
    if (n < 0)
        return b;
    return a;
}
```

You can of course simplify this to the following (thank you to @pickypg for the notice):

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(T a, T b) {
    return a.compareTo(b) < 1 ? b : a;
}
```

Comment: Why would you return `null` when they're equal? Return either one, otherwise your definition of `max` is a bit wonky.

Comment: @A.R.S.: Obviously the exact semantics would have to depend on the use case, but I think returning null would be quite surprising (and require extra code for a guard clause) for most purposes.

Comment: Now you get my +1. Note, you could simplify the logic to `return a.compareTo(b) < 1 ? b : a;`